# How to link a dll to Simulink?

Tags: dll, simulink

I need to use a dll file in my Simulink model. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [C S-Function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/f8-89503.html), and call into your dll from the methods in the S-Function, or you can use the [Legacy Code Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bq4g1es-1.html), which is probably easier than writing your own.

Comment: You can use the S-Function Builder block, which will simplify a lot(really, a lot!) the task of creating an s-function.